# Performing a nonlinear fit from data imported from a text file

Tags: import, fitting

I have a text file data that I imported and I want to fit it with a given equation. I tried to fit but it did not work and gives

Here is my code:

```
data = Import["https://pastebin.com/raw/ZJDbhdgB", "Table"];

p = 3.5346*10^21;    
k = 8.6173*10^-5;
g = 0.6361; 
i = 0.03;
b = 0.2;
e = 1.6*10^-19;
d = 0.001; 

curve = 
  NonlinearModelFit[
    data,
    p - 0.5*p*Sqrt[0.5*p^2+n^2*(Exp[-(g/k*x)])]*(1-m^2)/(p-0.5*p*Sqrt[0.5*p^2 + n^2*(E^-(g/k*x))]*(1 + m))^2,
    {n,m},x]
```

Comment: "but it did not work"  What exactly didn't work?  Did you get an error message?  It makes it more difficult to help if you don't supply the data or the error/warning messages.

Comment: It just gave me FittedModel[3.5346*10^21]

Comment: Did you try to restart the kernel? Also, what does `Dimension[data]` return? And can you provide some sample data/your actual data?

Comment: My guess is that you need to scale your data as the starting values are 1 for both `m` and `n` and likely those starting values are nowhere near the maximum likelihood estimates.  Alternatively, choosing better starting values might help.  Sharing some of your data (as @LukasLang) suggests would be very helpful.

Comment: Try evaluating your function with the starting values `p-0.5*p*Sqrt[0.5*p^2+n^2*(Exp[-(g/k*x)])]*(1-m^2)/(p-0.5*p*Sqrt[0.5*p^2+n^2*(E^-(g/k*x))]*(1+m^2))^2/.{n->1,m->1}` and you'll just get `3.5346*10^21`.  No `x` in there so there's no place to go for trying subsequent values of `n` and `m`.  You'll need either better starting values and/or get your equation to produce non-constant values.

Comment: Hi, here is sample data
420.750000000000 -0.0196500000000000
420              -0.0199500000000000
419.550000000000 -0.0201000000000000
419.250000000000 -0.0202500000000000
418.650000000000 -0.0204000000000000
417.900000000000 -0.0205500000000000
417.450000000000 -0.0208500000000000
416.850000000000 -0.0210000000000000
416.550000000000 -0.0211500000000000
416.100000000000 -0.0213000000000000
415.350000000000 -0.0214500000000000


The dimensions of the data is {995,2}

Comment: Please provide better data sample in your question, or all of the data through some external repository.

Comment: I uploaded the text file on Google drive of this link 

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1e6-_wXLMM2TfqnszRf6HaxuimeSHho7x/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Thanks for the data (I've put the data on pastebin and edited your question to load the data from there). Are you sure the units between the measured data and your parameters match? As @JimB already said, the scales of the numbers are very different and very extreme, resulting in terms like $e^{-10^6}$, which feels very wrong

Answer (score 0):

This is an extended comment that continues from the latest comment by @LukasLang:  Is your formula correct?

Here's what it looks like without substituting numbers in for the constants and performing some simplifications:

$$p-\frac{\left(1-m^2\right) \sqrt{n^2 e^{-\frac{g x}{k}}+\frac{p^2}{2}}}{2 \left(1-\frac{1}{2} (m+1) \sqrt{n^2 e^{-\frac{g x}{k}}+\frac{p^2}{2}}\right)^2}$$

Given that $p$ is so large, it certainly seems possible that the resulting equation is simply equal to $p$ for all practical purposes (which is what `NonlinearModelFit` is telling you).